# R: How to access to an element in rle object?

Tags: r

I wrote a code like this:

```
cf = rbinom(100, 1, 0.1)
count = rle(cf)
```

This return an `rle` object which contains two lists. (length and value). Say i want to access 3rd element in length list. How can i do this? I tried `count[1][3]` and `count[1, 3]` but it didn't work.

Comment: `count$lengths[3]`

Comment: Or `count[[1]][3]`, or `count[["lengths"]][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#convert to a dataframe, then access third row, 1st column   
data.frame(count[1])[3,1]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made